# Android in-app платежи

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

За последние две недели в приложении, судя по отчету из Firebase Analytics, было совершено 10 покупок, но при этом сумма дохода равная одной покупке и в Developer Console отображается только один заказ.

Возможно ли, что это фейковые покупки через freedom ?

[image: Статистика из Firebase Analytics][image: Отчеты заказов из Developer Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от аудитории, которая пользуется вашим приложением. Если основная масса - подростки, то практически гарантировано, что большая часть фальшивых покупок - это следствие использования Freedom и ему подобных программ.

В эту категорию могут также попасть покупки, затем оспоренные (например, родителями). Но %% таковых, как правило, невелик на общем фоне.